# How to prevent one administrator from disabling the account of another in Win10

Tags: windows-10, privileges, administration

I need to prevent any admin account from disabling the built-in administrator account. If this is possible in Win 10, please help.

Comment: It is not possible.  This is a human problem.  Enable  audting, have a single Auditor with access to those logs, and fire anyone who breaks policy.

Comment: You can't. One admin can do anything anything another admin can do and undo anything the other admin has done.

Comment: @DavidPostill, OK, understand. Can I allow user from some group (super users, etc.) to install applications which requires admin privileges without admin accept (the user must be able to act like admin until he faces with accounts administration or security settings interface)

Comment: @Iceman No .......